# Oracle form is not updatable after using WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have developed an Oracle form which is Master Details form. It does not allow insertion of new records but you can update records on the form. 
When I added a WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger on an item, the form disables updates. I am not able to change any value in the form and save it.

Answer (score 0):

WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger is bad choice to avoid inserts or updates on block. Set Insert-Allowed to False and Update-Allowed to True in block properties.

Comment: I am not using WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM to avoid inserts and updates. I have used SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY on ON-INSERT and ON-UPDATE for that and it was working fine until I used WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger for populating a field based on another field. If I remove this trigger, the form works as expected. Why is this unrelated WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM is disabling me to update the values in my form.

Comment: Provide your trigger code and the use case. I guess you need to allow insertion of detail records according to master data, right?